# Why the below ntfy command is not working with os.system() function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.system

On executing: `ntfy send 'Hello'`
through Windows cmd/Powershell, I am able to get a desktop notification. However, on executing the below command in Python 2.7 shell, I am getting error that 'ntfy is not recognised as internal or external command' in cmd:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('ntfy send \'hello\'')
```

Comment: Is your `PATH` the same in Powershell and in cmd?

Comment: If you type `ntfy` in a cmd window (not a Powershell window), does it work?

Answer (score 3):

The `ntfy` library is written in Python. So, if you have installed it with `pip`, you can just do:

```
import ntfy
ntfy.notify("My message", "Title")
```

You can also specify a backend. Ex.:

```
ntfy.notify("Hi!", "Greeting", backend="telegram")
```